# java regexp for reading number after certain symbol

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string

```
String names= D:45454546544654 A:45454545454 C:454545474
```

I need Output to be

```
String data[]=[45454546544654,45454545454,454545474]
```

Comment: split, then loop over Commons Lang StringUtils substringAfter(string, ':')

Comment: As usual with regular expression questions, this is under-specified. Is it just those letters in that order which is important? Or is it any letter, then a colon, then numbers? Is lower-case OK, what about strings larger than one letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than split you can just match:

```
(?<=:)\d+(?!\d)
```

Using this `Pattern`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=:)\\d+(?!\\d)");
```

Then you can use `Matcher.find` API to get all the matches.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB0fY5/2)

Comment: Hi @anubhava can you give me solution to finding from ABC:202sec GPS:30sec and i need the only digit value. like 202 30

Comment: I need the digit value of GPS i.e 30

Comment: ok check updated regex and new demo.

Comment: Thanks bro :) worked :) Where do i learn regexp

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info is pretty god site for regex

Answer (score 2):

First replace all the uppercase letter plus the following colon `:` with an empty string and then split the resultant string according to the spaces.

```
String names = "D:45454546544654 A:45454545454 C:454545474";
String parts[] = names.replaceAll("[A-Z]:", "").split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[45454546544654, 45454545454, 454545474]
```